# Spritesheet vs map of individual sprites, Android performance

Tags: android

Currently I have all of my sprites as individual images, 186 bitmaps in all but not all of them are used in each level. So, when a level is loading, only the sprites needed for that level are loaded into a hashmap (typically about 40-80). When scrolling over my tilemap, I simply reference these bitmaps in the hashmap to draw on the canvas

Initially this seemed like the simplest approach so it's what I went with. That said, is there any reason to consider using sprite sheets instead? If so, what would the advantages be? Using sprite sheets seems to be very popular from what I have gathered on the internet, but i'm not sure why, or why it would be better than what I am currently doing.

Thanks for any thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sprite sheet is used when you need to pack many small images into one file for to increase the speed of sending them through web. If you do not have problems with sending many small thingies, use it as you do - it is much more effective model for **use**.
Why they are in fashion? Because all web techs are in fashion. (a little exagerrating here :-)

If we'll look into the problem deeper, much depends on **how** do you realize that image map, where do you place them into (DB or files), how often to you reload them and many other details that could easily reverse the results of comparison. If you need really so deep research, simply do the comparative testing.